# Getting records from three tables with sometimes unmatching fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a question that should be easy to answer...

I have a table called `Projects`, primary key is `ProjectId`.

Second table is called `ProjectResources`, with `ProjectId` as a foreign key, plus fields for user and hours (represents the users assigned to work on the project)

Third table is `TimesheetEntries` (which the users use to record hours users actually worked on a project), with `ProjectId` as foreign Key, and field `User`

What is required is for me to show the records of the `projectId,BudgetedHours` (from `ProjectResources` table) and `ActualHours` (from the `TimesheetEntries` table); I would like however to include the following cases where:

1. a user was assigned to the project but did not work on it (in this case the budgeted hours should have a value and the actual hours should have zero)
2. a user was not assigned to the project but has nonetheless worked on it (in which case the BudgetedHours should be zero and the ActualHours should have a value)
3. a user was both assigned to the project and has worked on it (both BudgetedHours and ActualHours have values)

Could somebody direct me to a T-SQL statement to get this kind of result?

Comment: Have you chosen an answer for this?  If so could you mark it or reply?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
SELECT p.ProjectId, 
       (CASE WHEN pr.[User] Is NULL THEN te.[User] ELSE pr.[User] END) as [User], 
       IsNull(pr.BudgetedHours, 0.0), 
       IsNull(Sum(te.ActualHours), 0.0)
FROM Project p
LEFT JOIN ProjectResources pr on p.ProjectId = pr.ProjectId
LEFT JOIN TimeSheetEntries te on p.p.ProjectId = te.ProjectId
GROUP BY p.ProjectId, te.User, pr.BudgetedHours
```

But I'm guessing at your field names, etc. so you would need to adapt this for your own domain.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason you are having problems is because you are thinking about the actual hours and the budgeted hours as being all essentially equal, because they are assigned to the project.

However, the actual and budgeted are calculated in very different ways.  You need to calculate them using separate subqueries, as in the following example:

```
select coalesce(budget.ProjectId, actual.ProjectId) as ProjectId,
       budget.BudgetedHours, actual.ActualHours
from 
(
  select projectid, sum(pr.hours) as BudgetedHours
  from Projects p 
  left outer join ProjectResources pr
) budget 
full outer join
(
  select projectid, sum(tse.hours) as ActualHours
  from  Projects p 
  left outer join TimeSheetEntries tse
     on tse.ProjectId = p.ProjectId
) actual
  on budget.ProjectId = actual.ProjectId
```